# Is it the C++20 module and range is completely available in all compilers ( MSVC, CLang, GCC)

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, clang, c++20

I am trying to find an official document to show to my team that We are good to use c++20 now. But There is no document mentioned that all compiler already fully support the c++20. so Should I use C++20 for the new project.

Comment: C++20 support is still partial and experimental in most compilers. (even the standard itself is still being modified through defect reports...)

Comment: gcc has almost completed all C++20 core language features, while msvc has almost completed all C++20 library features. You can get the latest progress of the three major compilers from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the C++ reference website to see what is supported in what toolchains (and what versions), the modules might not be as widely supported as you would hope. However, if you know exactly what tools you and your team are using and you know exactly what parts of the standard you want (and what risks it involves), then you could theoretically use some parts of the standard.

For myself, I will be using modules on my own projects wherever I can, but (in **2021** when this answer was written) it feels to me too early to propose it in a team. Of course this answer changes over time and then it will be obvious 'yes it's supported, unless you use legacy toolchains'.

## Modules(P1103R3)

- GCC 11 **partial**
- Clang 8 **partial**
- MSVC 19.0 (VS 2015) **partial**, 19.10 (VS 2017) **TS only**, 19.28 (VS 2019) **16.8**
- Apple Clang 10.0.1 **partial** (Xcode 10.2 10E125, Xcode 10.2.1 10E1001, Xcode 10.3 10G8)
- EDG eccp **no**
- Intel C++ **no**
- IBM XLC++ **no**
- Sun/Oracle C++ **no**
- Embarcadero C++ Builder **no**
- Cray **no**
- Nvidia HPC C++ (ex Portland Group/PGI) **no**
- Nvidia nvcc **no**

#### References:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

#### GCC

C++20 core language support status(complete as of 11.0, except part of modules)

https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20

### Clang

https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20

https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/Cxx2aStatus.html

#### Apple Clang

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes

#### MSVS

https://github.com/microsoft/STL/wiki/Changelog

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp17-20-features-and-fixes-in-vs-2019/

## Range

I'm not sure which one you are meaning, this one?

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r4.pdf

Then that's supported:

- GCC 10 **yes**
- Clang 13 **partial**
- MSVC 19.29 **yes** (VS 2019 16.10)
- Apple Clang **no**
- EDG eccp **no**
- Intel C++ **no**
- IBM XLC++ **no**
- Sun/Oracle C++ **no**
- Embarcadero C++ Builder **no**
- Cray **no**
- Nvidia HPC C++ (ex Portland Group/PGI) **no**
- Nvidia nvcc **no**